# Angular/Java Script ; Template Initialises Before HTTP Get complete

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I P control the initialisation of the variables in ngOnInit ()?

I have a service that fetches data from the server via Angular HTTPClient and  get() method.  I Then I take the data and want to use it in the blog component.

I have 3 separate variables. All the blogs, HeroBlog and PrimaryBlog.
heroBlog and primaryBlog are being executed before the subscription method. and are not initialised,  please see the code below

Blog Post Service

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Blog } from '../_interfaces/blog.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BlogPostService {

    heroBlogSubject  = new Subject <Blog> ();
    primaryBlogSubject  = new Subject <Blog> ();
    blogPostsSubject = new Subject <Blog []>();
    allBlogs:Blog [] = [];

    constructor ( private httpClnt :HttpClient){}
    //Get Blogs From Server
    getBlogsFromServer (){
      return this.httpClnt.get('https://bc-blog-86b3b.firebaseio.com/blogs.json').pipe(
            map((response) => {
                for (const key in response) {
                    if (response.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        this.allBlogs.push( {...response[key], blogKey:key});
                    }
                }
                this.heroBlogSubject.next(this.allBlogs[this.allBlogs.length-1]);
                return this.allBlogs.reverse();
            
            }));   
    }
}
```

Blog Post Component

```
export class BlogComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

    blogs: Blog [];
    heroBlog: Blog;
    primaryBlog: Blog;
    blogSubscription: Subscription;
    dataRecived : boolean;
    constructor(private blgServ: BlogPostService){
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.blgServ.getBlogsFromServer().subscribe( (responseData)=>{
        this.dataRecived = false;
        
        this.heroBlog = responseData [0]
        this.primaryBlog = responseData [1];
        this.blogs = responseData;
        this.dataRecived = true;
      });
    }
```

As you can see I am trying to assign the heroBlog and primaryBlog within the Subscribe(). However,  the initial declaration is getting executed first causing the template not to display the 2 blogs and also causing error.

How should I implement/initialise these two variable upon ngOnit(), or how should make sure all my attributes have value beef the screen renders?

Comment: either initialize this.heroBlog  and this.primaryBlog as empty arrays or have *ngIf="heroBlog" in your html so that the items dont start rendreing until they have value which will help avoid errors

Comment: Thanks a lot. 'ngIf' is the way forward, I now get the desired behaviour. Appreciate your help. Have a wonderful weekend.